# Unique Sub-JSon object of a Json object in C#

Tags: json, linq, c#-4.0

let me start from a JSon object like

```
[
  {
    "id": 32837732,
    "composer": {
      "id": 536,
      "name": "Francis Poulenc"
    },
    "title": "Of Thee I Sing: Overture (radio version)"
  },
  {
    "id": 32837735,
    "composer": {
      "id": 245,
      "name": "George Gershwin"
    },
    "title": "Concerto in F : I. Allegro"
  },
  {
    "id": 32837739,
    "composer": {
      "id": 245,
      "name": "George Gershwin"
    },
    "title": "Concerto in F : II. Adagio"
  }
]
```

is it possible to get, with C#, Linq, in a clean, declarative way, a Json like

```
{
'composer': [
                {
                'id': '536',
                'name': 'Francis Poulenc'
                },
                {
                'id': '245',
                'name': 'George Gershwin'
                },
        ]
}
```

That is a JSon object with the unique sub-values for each composer (id and name)?
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert and you'll need to create coresponding classes in order to deserialize and serialize the object.

This is how the classes would look like

```
public class YourObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Composer composer { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

}

public class Composer
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class JsonResult
{
    public List<Composer> composer { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code where you do a group by composer id and name and take the first one for each group, this will ensure that you have unique id's and names

```
string jsonString =
    "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": 32837732,\r\n    \"composer\": {\r\n      \"id\": 536,\r\n      \"name\": \"Francis Poulenc\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"title\": \"Of Thee I Sing: Overture (radio version)\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": 32837735,\r\n    \"composer\": {\r\n      \"id\": 245,\r\n      \"name\": \"George Gershwin\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"title\": \"Concerto in F : I. Allegro\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": 32837739,\r\n    \"composer\": {\r\n      \"id\": 245,\r\n      \"name\": \"George Gershwin\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"title\": \"Concerto in F : II. Adagio\"\r\n  }\r\n]";
List<YourObject> yourList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourObject>>(jsonString);
List<Composer> composers = yourList.Select(t => t.composer).GroupBy(t => new { t.name, t.id }).Select(t => t.First()).ToList();
JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult { composer = composers };
var jsonResultString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult);
```

Here is a full csharppad with the result printed out http://csharppad.com/gist/5a39f78b1878738fa0181495bb6e3f6e

Comment: Thanks ! I was able to adapt your code to my "real" situation and it works perfectly !